# Massive issue with moderators

Tags: discussion

I had originally decided to drop this and just not come back to these forums after the way I was treated, but something badly needs to be done. I tried asking the same question multiple times in different ways. Every time I gave all information in detail about the issue I was happening. No matter what I wrote, the moderators kept closing my question. They even went as far as telling me that I wouldn't receive any help with my question if I asked it elsewhere. I asked on other forums and received an answer within the hour. Meanwhile the same moderators keep allowing completely irrelevant questions like "does all water return to the ocean", which has absolutely nothing to do with blender. They also allow question with so many misspelled words that it is barely legible. I asked another question about another problem I was having which was also immediately closed. The response was to report it as a bug. The question was not even given a chance. There was a good chance that it was something I was doing wrong, and it turned out it was. It was something I was doing, and had nothing to do with a bug, but because they closed my question, it took me 4 days to figure out what was going on. I tried getting help for these problems and received canned messages from the contact form. I tried asking for help on here and was harassed and lied to by moderators. This completely defeats the purpose of these forums.

Comment: hello, could you link the original questions you are talking about?

Comment: Please link the questions you posted here so we can see what you wrote. I also was very angry about some moderators here…don’t be angry. They are not worth your anger. There are a lot of „good“ people here, but I can completely understand your feelings.

Comment: Maybe there are some „good“ moderators who start checking what „some“ moderators are doing here and how they „poison“ this forum.

Answer (score 3):

Don't take it personally; first of all you need to know that stack sites are not regular discussion forum but question and answer one.

For this sites it is require every new thread to be started with a question and every response to that question to be an attempt at answering it. As stated [HERE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums)

Because of that, the questions needs to be clear and thoroughly explained, this is not only for the **description** but also for the attached **images** and **files**. Sometimes you could make an good description but it could be hard to imagine your workflow without images to support the description, other times it is hard even with the images and descriptions, and you might need to add a Blend file that contains the issue, and it is always recommended to **keep all those thing until you get an answer** (if someone has it) because it could be hard for you to test that answer if you don't have the original files.

When a question is closed it's based on a vote system made by other users with enough reputation to do that and it's nothing personal. Some people could vote to close your question and post a comment on why they think the question should be closed. There are a lot of questions here and sometimes also happens that misleading questions are still open because probably no user saw them at the moment and moderators with the power to close those question probably did not notice all of them (Human error, nothing personal), this is why it is important to report those if you see one.

And there is something else and the reason for me to say is not personal, internet is an anonymous place and as we all know, there are a lot of people that can't express themselves in a polite way or they don't want to because no one can't see them.

Yes, this site is very strict compare to other sites but I think it's just to keep the web as a question and answer without much discussions in order for future users to get the answer that they need.

Happens to all of us, but don't let that experience make you think the entire site is full of the same people.

Comment: I don't have the original question because I went though and deleted all of my content and deleted my account. I don't plan on returning until this situation is fixed.

"Because of that, the questions needs to be clear and thoroughly explained"
- As previously stated, my question was well written and included all details.

Comment: "When a question is closed it's base on a vote system made by other users with enough reputation to do that and it's nothing personal. Some people could vote to close your question and post a comment on why they think the question should be closed"
- There were no votes on my question at any time. There were however 2 comments by people trying to help. I also did ask my question on other forums and received an answer within the hour.

Comment: "There are a lot of questions here and sometimes also happens that misleading questions are still open because probably no user saw them at the moment and moderators with the power to close those question probably did not notice all of them (Human error, nothing personal), this is why it is important to report those if you see one."
- There were responses to the question I saw "does all water return to the ocean", which means it was seen enough for it to be closed, if not deleted.

Comment: You keep saying "Don't take it personal" and said "Happens to all of us, but don't let that experience make you think the entire site is full of the same people."
- I didn't take it personal. I saw a major issue and I made a statement about it, that was not unfounded and not without valid reason. This site has too many of the same kind of people or this would not have happened. As I said before, something badly needs to be done. This issue defeats the purpose of this site.

Comment: @JustMe: Do not let other people frustrate you. There are always a small percentage of people who will annoy or will try to annoy you. Maybe it is intentionally maybe it is because that kind of people have no self reflection. The problem is: if the "good" people give up here, the "bad" ones will take over and the forum will be quickly dead. It's like that: If all live like "the wiser gives in" then we will be ruled by idiots.